# codeigniter phil sturgeon template , how to pass variable to partial view with set_partial() method

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am using phil sturgeon's codeigniter template engine but i have problem how to pass variable to partial view with **set_partial()** method. 
I used :

```
$this->template->set_partial('name_partial','path/to/partial',$_data_to_pass);
```

but when in view I use `var_dump($data_to_pass)` the variable seem does not exist.
I read in the documentation that it is possible to pass extra data only to partial with that function.

Comment: Try $config['parser_enabled'] = TRUE; in your config/template.php

Answer (score 1):

If there's somebody have the some problem, passing any `$_data_to_pas` as array but still does not be recognized, try to open libraries/template.php and find this line (inside `public function build`):

`$template['partials'][$name] = $this->_find_view($partial['view'], $partial['data'],`**TRUE**`);`

change to:

`$template['partials'][$name] = $this->_find_view($partial['view'], $partial['data'],`**FALSE**`);`

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your variabele _data_to_pass is an array. You're passing the content of this array to the view and not the array. So only the content of this array exists in the view.

Answer (score 0):

As @Swerk says, you need to pass the data as an array. Try changing this line:

```
$this->template->set_partial('name_partial','path/to/partial',$_data_to_pass);
```

To this:

```
$this->template->set_partial('name_partial','path/to/partial',array('data_to_pass' = > $_data_to_pass));
```

And then check in your partial view var_dump($data_to_pass);

Comment: I got it. thank you for your help, the only way to retrive the variable is by using parser . it cannot show in PHP way like <?php echo $data_to_pass; ?> but it only show with {data_to_pass}. but why? i stuck on this.